# aspx & asp difference in calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp-classic

I've manage to create an aspx page that contains an image slider which derived from a javascript function, but when I copy the code to an (.asp) page, the image slider does not load properly.

So I would like to ask if there's any difference in the method of calling javascript function in asp classic (.asp) and ASP.net (.aspx)?

Thanks :)

```
<!--BANNER CODING -->
<div id="banner_image">
    <div id="slider-wrapper">
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <img src="images/home_1.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="images/home_2.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="images/1.png" alt="" />
            <img src="images/2.png" alt="" />
            <img src="images/hom_3.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="images/home_4.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <!--close slider-->
        <br />
    </div>
    <!--close slider_wrapper-->
</div>
<!--close banner_image-->
```

Comment: I suggest that you give [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx) a read first - there's some useful info about just how JavaScript is handled by ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

No, there should be absolutely no difference as JavaScript is completely client-side. The only issue could be missing the proper js file, or that the files (js,css,images) are in directories whose path is different in the .asp page.

Also, if the .aspx page is based on a master, the javascript files could be referenced in the .master in which case they wouldn't have been copied over. Also make sure that the script that initializes the nivoSlider is copied onto the .asp page. Otherwise, there is absolutely zero difference since the browser only knows that they are both HTML by the time the pages get to it.